# Wrapper function for `styled`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, template-literals

Currently I'm using tailwind with styled components like this.

```
const Container = styled.div.attrs({ 
    className: 'flex flex-col h-screen justify-center items-center' 
})`
    background-color: white;
`;
```

I would like to create a "wrapper" function, that I could call like this

```
const Container = myStyled('div','flex flex-col h-screen justify-center items-center')`
    background-color: white;
`;

const Container2 = myStyled(Container,'text-6xl')`
    background-color: red;
`;
```

How do I create a tagged template literals string that can accept parameters and then pass it on to `styled` from styled components?

Answer (score 0):

Styled components can be wrapped by other styled components using `styled(otherStyledElement)` like so:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Container2>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </Container2>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div.attrs({ className: 'df'})`
  background: red;

`;

const Container2 = styled(Container).attrs({ className: 'df'})`
  background: blue;
`;
```

CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-63996579-styles-stacked-thwf3

Comment: That’s what i’m using now. I would like to change `styled(Container).attrs({ className: 'df'})` to `myStyled(Container, ‘df’)`